# append message to tee

Tags: bash, tee

is there any way to add the current date when using tee? For example:

```
ls -al | tee someFile.txt
```

prints something along these lines:

```
== 23.10.2014 - 23:23:23 ==
...
Whatever the ls returned
...
```

It has to be done as a single command. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you're actually asking for is *prepending*, not appending.

```
{ echo "some prefix"; ls -al; } | tee someFile.txt
```

If you wanted to *append* a message, though, the syntax is exactly what you'd expect given the above:

```
{ ls -al; echo "some suffix"; } | tee someFile.txt
```

Comment: You are right I meant prepend. although it doesn't fully solve my problem, your answer is correct for the case I explained. I have opened a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542882/prepend-message-to-rsstail) to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For any command:

`<command> | tee -a <filename>`

OR

`<command> | tee --append <filename>`