# Prepend message to rsstail

Tags: bash, awk, tee

I am trying to prepend a message to the output of rsstail, this is what I have right now:

```
rsstail -o -i 15 --initial 0 http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/europe/rss.xml | awk -v time=$( date +\[%H:%M:%S_%d/%m/%Y\] ) '{print time,$0}' | tee someFile.txt
```

which should give me the following:

```
[23:46:49_23/10/2014] Title: someTitle
```

After the command I have a `| while read line do ... end` which never gets called because the above command does not output a single thing. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using the python version of rsstail, since the other one kept on crashing (https://github.com/gvalkov/rsstail.py)

**EDIT:**

As requested in the comments the command:

```
rsstail -o -i 15 --initial 0 http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/europe/rss.xml
```

Will give back a message like the following when a new article is found

```
Title: Sweden calls off search for sub
```

Comment: Can you please paste the sample output of rsstail -o -i 15 --initial 0 http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/europe/rss.xml. Dont expect people will know what rsstail is and what it does.

Comment: Your `awk` commands works fine for me.  Your problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: @almasshaikh I have added the output you requested

Comment: @John1024 Are you using the C version or the python version of rsstail?

Comment: @user2287089 I checked _only_ the `awk` portion of the command: it worked as it was supposed to work.  I didn't use `rsstail`.  As per almas suggestion, I think it would help if you included a sample of the output of your `rsstail` command here.

Comment: am not sure what your while loop does further but using awk it works for me echo "Title: Sweden calls off search for sub" | awk -v time=$( date +\[%H:%M:%S_%d/%m/%Y\] ) '{print time,$0}' | tee files.txt | awk '{print $0}'

Comment: I have added it, it's in the original post

Comment: @user2287089 So, your `rsstail` command is working.  The `awk` command works for both almas shaikh and me.  That leads me to suspect the problem is in the `while` loop.

Comment: @John1024 Funnily enough, rsstail works when alone, but when I substitute it to the echo command, the whole thing falls to pieces...looks like the chaining of the commands makes it fail. Right now the while loop is not a concern

Comment: Perhaps the problem is output buffering in rsstail or elsewhere?  For example, if you run `rsstail` directly in the terminal, it prints right away, right?  What if you pipe that same command to `cat`?  If it no longer prints right away, it's buffering.

Comment: @JohnZwinck This is ridiculous...if I run `rsstail -o -i 15 --initial 0 http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/europe/rss.xml | cat | tee aFile.txt` it works...looks like there is an incompatibility between `awk` and `rsstail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my `rsstail` is different from yours, but mine supports the option

```
-Z x    add heading 'x'
```

so that

```
rsstail -Z"$( date +\[%H:%M:%S_%d/%m/%Y\] ) " ...
```

does the job without `awk`; on the other hand, you do have some problem with buffering, is it possible to ask `rsstail` to stop after a given number of titles?

Comment: You are right, I am using the Python version of rsstail, being as the other one kept on crashing. But if you say it works this way, I might as well give it a shot

Comment: I have just stumbled upon http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe , have a look and see if this can get what you need,

Comment: So this kind of solved my problem...I had to fix a couple of issues with my `apt-get` command, but I was able to install your same version of `rsstail`. By using the `-Z` option it works perfectly. Thanks!